# MouseDown Event VBA

Tags: vba, treeview, mouseevent, powerpoint, userform

I'm trying to allow users to drag and drop nodes in a TreeView so that they can be re-ordered.

One necessary piece of code is the mouse down event which I have defined as such:

```
Private Sub TreeView1_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
```

The error I am seeing is:

> "Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having the same name"

Which means something is wrong with the syntax of the MouseDown event declaration.

But according to the Office Dev Center, the syntax should be

```
Private Sub Form_MouseDown(Button As Integer, _ 
     Shift As Integer, X As Single, _ 
     Y As Single)
```

My syntax looks fine, is there maybe a library I'm missing? I'm running Office 2016.

Comment: Try `As Long` for the last two parameters

Comment: Your syntax is correct for the form's MouseUp/MouseDown events; for treeview it's TreeView1_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As stdole.OLE_XPOS_PIXELS, ByVal Y As stdole.OLE_YPOS_PIXELS)  I don't know more than that, as I've not used the control, but perhaps that'll be a start.

Comment: You two are awesome.
**Tim Williams**  - thank you for the suggestion, it didn't quite work out but I appreciate the help!
**Steve Rindsberg** -   This was fantastic. It's a good start and the program compiled just fine. Now it's onto the real challenges I suppose.
Thank you both very much.